# How to read the map output file generated by a project using Cartographer without ROS

Tags: sensors, slam, imu

Currently I can successfully generate the map output file but I have no idea how to display it in practice. Basically, it should be a 2D SLAM map.

The project I'm using is available at the following [link](https://github.com/dahogn/cartographer_2d_demo/) on Github. This project basically uses Google Cartographer 2D SLAM **without ROS.**

Compiling the project I get an output file called "map_output" but it seems to be completely raw: it's not even binary. How can I convert or read it in a viewable format?

Inside the main file, specifically inside the [main function](https://github.com/dahogn/cartographer_2d_demo/blob/master/main.cpp#L35), it can be seen how data consisting of inertial measurements (IMU) is taken as input and processed to provide an output map.

**Update:** map_output file as requested is available [here.](https://github.com/gcantoni/cartographer_2d_demo/blob/master/map_output) (IMU data file is available [here.](https://github.com/gcantoni/cartographer_2d_demo/blob/master/data/record_imu_radar)) I'm pretty sure both can be read and/or represented in the same way.

Comment: Can you share that `map_output` file, or a small version of it, or cut and paste some of the contents into your question, or link to an example in the same format?

Comment: @LucasW Absolutely! I've updated my question with the link to the file. The "format" (it doesn't actually have one) is the same as the IMU data.

Comment: Ok it looks like a big dumb array of bytes where 0xff maybe means free-space or blank/unmapped?  With maybe a 32 byte header at the start, possibly containing the width and height, though I don't see it write out a header in the code

Comment: I recommend loading it in jupyter-notebook if you are at all familiar with that or at least python, load it into a 2d numpy array and imshow it (maybe using width and height you got from a different source if it isn't in the file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From hexdump I see a lot the two rows of 16 bytes each that don't match the next rows which are mostly `0xff`:

```
hexdump -C map_output  | more
00000000  46 00 00 00 dc 00 00 00  00 00 00 d4 cc cc fc bf  |F...............|
00000010  00 00 40 6b 66 66 23 c0  00 00 00 a0 99 99 a9 3f  |..@kff#........?|
00000020  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
*
...
00000350  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
*
00000370  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 36  2e 31 ff ff ff ff ff ff  |.......6.1......|
00000380  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff 30 ff  |..............0.|
00000390  30 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |0...............|
000003a0  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
```

The file size is 15432 bytes, so 15400 bytes without that header, width * height = 154300 - so find factors using https://stackoverflow.com/a/70924583/603653

It looks like you can open it in the gimp by checking `Show All Files` then select `Raw Image Data` :[image]

You then have to input the width and height manually, image type indexed, and set the offset to 32:

[image][image]

If that looks completely wrong then maybe some other import settings will work, but to me it looks a little like a 2D laser scan from a fixed location.

Answer (score 2):

The map file from that executable is written out [here in the code](https://github.com/dahogn/cartographer_2d_demo/blob/0780602bf6ae3c4acc106889774921d4536e971d/main.cpp#L112)  It looks to be populated from the `CartoModule::paint_map` function [here in the code](https://github.com/dahogn/cartographer_2d_demo/blob/0780602bf6ae3c4acc106889774921d4536e971d/main.cpp#L78).

This appears to be an [undocumented custom implementation from the project that you're linking to](https://github.com/dahogn/cartographer_2d_demo/blob/0780602bf6ae3c4acc106889774921d4536e971d/carto.cpp#L128) so you'll have to read the code there to find out why/how to interpret it.